# Training Hidden Markov Models using Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, mathematical-optimization, markov-chains, markov-process

I have created a Hidden Markov Process with an initial probability vector, emission and transmission matrices.

```
hmm = HiddenMarkovProcess[Table[1/21, {i, 1, 21}], tm, em]
```

**popup question**: What sort of an object is my hmm now? Its `Head[]` gives `HiddenMarkovProcess`. And in the documentation I have seen many functions like `LogLikelihood[]` that take as a parameter a process or *proc*. I'm not sure I understand what "type" *proc* is. Is it atomic structure in *Mathematica* like `String` and such?

Anyway, I now have a large annotated data that I want my HMM to classify them into 2 classes. Having the list of annotated emission strings, basically I want to minimize the log-likelihood function using gradient descent or the Baum-Welch E-M algorithm. I saw a high-level function called `EstimatedProcess` to which I can give a process and say estimate by Baum-Welch. Will this update my transmission and emission matrices?
Also can I pass the functions like `LogLikelihood` to the function `Minimize` and just then use the option `GradientDescent` or anything of the sort?

Note: I don't want to use the `Classify` function since I want to have my custom made HMM.